# MySQL Import ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String

Tags: mysql, joomla, phpmyadmin

I get the following error when trying to import a MySQL database with phpMyAdmin. I am not sure how the dump was created:

There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

```
ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 108
STR: |//**
SQL: -- Database lach

    -- Table structure for table jos_acajoom_lists

|------
|Field|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**id**//|int(10)|Yes|NULL
|**list_name**|varchar(101)|Yes|
|list_desc|text|Yes|NULL
|list_type|tinyint(2)|Yes|0
|sendername|varchar(64)|Yes|
|senderemail|varchar(64)|Yes|
|bounceadres|varchar(64)|Yes|
|layout|text|Yes|NULL
```

Comment: this is your table structure , but how u importing ..paste that code..

Comment: i tried using phpMyAdmin import (from a .sql file) and also running the script from phpMyAdmin but i get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might be trying to use a "//" to comment out a line in the import. You will need to replace that with "-- ", as MySQL does not support the C++ style comments.