# SQL Error when importing backup into phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, import, backup

Hi I am getting the below error when importing a backup into phpmyadmin. Any Ideas why I am getting this?

There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

```
ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 593 STR: /> SQL: 
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 2.11.4
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Jan 12, 2013 at 11:54 AM
-- Server version: 5.1.57
-- PHP Version: 5.2.17

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";# MySQL returned an empty result
set (i.e. zero rows).
```

Comment: Did you try googling it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Import ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879219/mysql-import-error-unknown-punctuation-string)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have magic_quotes enabled somewhere in your php.ini?

http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php